# Ruby on Rails, creating Has_and_belong_to_many object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following tables: Account, Address and Contacts

I want an Account to have many addresses, and contacts to have many addresses.

First I have created foreign_keys for Account and contact in the Address, but it end up having the two fields in the create form, so I have changed the association to Has_and_belongs_to_many and created joint tables accounts_addresses and contacts_addresses. But now I'm lost how to create new Accounts and Contact address from their view. Can someone help me?

How to create the association with account or address at the same time I'm creating the new_address??

I want to use new_address and edit_address view on address for both Account and Addresses, but I dont know how to configure the controller to receive the Account or Address id and create address and association at the same time.

I have the new_address link, passing the Account ID to the new controller:

```
<%= link_to new_address_path(:account_id => @accounts.id) do %>
<%= (image_tag("address_new.png", :width => "70%")) %>
<br /> New Address
<% end %>
```

But in the controller Im completely lost:
    class AddressesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user

```
def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:id, :no, :street, :suburb, :code, :details , :city, :state, :country, :account, :contact)
end

def new
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New")

        @addresses = @account.addresses.new(:account_id => params[:account_id])
        @addresses = @contact.addresses.new(:contact_id => params[:contact_id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New !Access Denied! ")
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresss."
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
    end
end

def create
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create", details: address_params)
        @address = Address.new(address_params)
        if @address.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Address Saved'
        redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)      
        else
        render "new"
        end
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create !Access Denied! ")
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresss."
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
    end
end


def edit
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit", details: params[:id])
        @addresss = Address.find(params[:id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresss."
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
    end
end

def update
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Update", details: address_params)
        @addresss = Address.find(params[:id])
        if @addresss.update_attributes(address_params)
        redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
            flash[:notice] = 'Account Updated'
        else 
        render "edit"
        flash[:error]
        end
    else
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresss."
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
    end
end

def show
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canread?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View", details: params[:id])
        @addresses = @account.addresses.find(:account => params[:account_id])
        @addresses = @contact.addresses.find(:contact => params[:contact_id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to view Addresss."
    redirect_to roles_path
    end
end

def destroy
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:candelete?)
        @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Delete", details: params[:id])
        @addresses.destroy
        redirect_to roles_path
        flash[:notice] = 'Address Deleted'
    else
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to delete Addresss."
    redirect_to role_path
    end
end

# Before Filters

# Confirms if User is logged-in
def logged_in_user
 unless logged_in?
 flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
 redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

end

Comment: You didn't show your code: models/views you have troubles with, reproducing everything in head is quite complicated. I suggest you to add it and point the place where you have problems.

Comment: Why are you using `has_and_belongs_to_many`? I would think that an address can only belong to a single contact or account. In this case a standard one-to-many association (using `belongs_to` and `has_many`) would be simpler to manage. You could consider a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) if Address can belong to several entities.

Comment: Yeah, I have changed back, to belongs_to and has many, I thought that using a joint table for both would make it simplier, but in fact it makes it worse, seems like Amanda's answers below solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a polymorphic association and nested attributes. Take a look at this [blog post](http://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/), where they describe what these two things are, and then take you through the steps for the migration, modifying the models, and creating a shared view (their example is even for addresses :) ).

Comment: Thanks Amanda, is something like this I need, but the thing is that I need to have more than one address for each contact and account.

Comment: Amanda, do you think this could work?

the polyphormic with:

    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, :through => :addressable
    end

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Changed Account and Contact models to has many address as and used polyphormic to associate address models with many accounts and contacts.

I followed the ruby guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations